# Python DataFrame repeating column dynamically with calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I have a function that will do some calculations made in other parts of the code. I have it dynamically repeat the calculations based on the number of input (binary) a user indicates in an earlier section. The calculations are working but I cannot get this to create multiple columns in the dataframe. How can I get the function to create a new column for each repeat of the "while" loop? Is that even possible? I tried creating 9 columns to see if that would work but I get a "mismatched columns" error.

```
def multipleldlc():
    outputldlc = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ldldcisfhprob1", "ldldcisfhprob2", "ldldcisfhprob3", "ldldcisfhprob4", "ldldcisfhprob5", "ldldcisfhprob6", "ldldcisfhprob7", "ldldcisfhprob8", "ldldcisfhprob9"])
    y = 0
    numcols = len(binary[0])
    print(numcols)
    while y < numcols:
        for item in binary:
            for i, j in pinput.iterrows():
                agej =j.values[0]
                ldlcj = j.values[1]
                totalcj = j.values[2]
                ldlcisfh = ldlcfh(agej, ldlcj, totalcj)
                ldlcisnotfh = ldlcfh(agej, ldlcj, totalcj)
                if item[y] == 0:
                    ldlcprob = ldlcisnotfh
                    outputldlc.loc[i] = [ldlcprob]
                else:
                    ldlcprob = ldlcisfh
                    outputldlc.loc[i] = [ldlcprob]
        y += 1
    print(outputldlc)
    return outputldlc
```

Comment: Why do you need a while loop in the first place? What does the input data look like, what is the desired output? There are probably easier ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @RJAdriaanse
Basically, I am working on creating a predictive analytics tool that takes input from the user, can have up to 9 people's information entered. It then takes the info entered and runs some calculations I have created, that is what the ldlcfh function calculates. It calculates a probability for family history and non-family history. I then have a binary table for every possible outcome of 1 or 0 for the 9 people, which puts out a 512 row 9 column binary table. Each column in the binary is a person, column 1 = person 1. I want this function to run all rows based on column input.

Comment: I imagine there is an easier way to do this, my Python skills are mediocre compared to my data analysis skills. This is just how I thought I could do it.

Comment: Can't you store the people